# How to style paper-card (Polymer 3) included inside a LitElement custom component using a mixin

Tags: polymer, polymer-3.x, lit-element

I created a custom element using LitElement in Polymer 3. I included a paper-card element inside that custom element. I would like to use the style mixins already defined to style that paper-card but I can't. For example, `paper-card` define this mixin:

```
--paper-card-header-text
```

https://www.webcomponents.org/element/@polymer/paper-card/elements/paper-card

I tried almost everything to use that mixin inside my custom element, but doesn't work. For example:

```
`paper-card{
      --paper-card-header-text:{
         color: blue;
      }
    }`
```

I also imported the mixin polyfill but nothing

```
`import @webcomponents/shadycss/entrypoints/apply-shim.js;`
```

I need help Thanks

Comment: I don't know why but Instead, you can change the color of header text with `paper-card { --paper-card-header-color:blue; }`

Comment: Thanks, but my question is more related to how to use the style mixin as  paper-card-header-color is not a mixin

Answer (score 0):

To use the CSS mixin:

1. Import the [Shady CSS *ApplyShim*](https://github.com/webcomponents/shadycss) in `index.html`:

   ```
   <script src="./node_modules/@webcomponents/shadycss/apply-shim.min.js"></script>
   ```
2. In your custom element's `render()`, insert the CSS mixin in the `<style>` block:

   ```
   class MyElement extends LitElement {
     render() {
       return html`
         <style>
           paper-card {
             --paper-card-header-text: {
               color: blue;
             };
           }
         </style>
         <paper-card>...</paper-card>
         `
     }
   }
   ```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/lit-element-css-mixin-nkdduq?file=index.js)

Answer (score 0):

CSS mixins were used by Polymer, but don't work with Lit's adopted stylesheets. You can add a `<style>` to the template then run the apply styles script to it, but this is clunky and can result in a flash of unstyled DOM before it changes.

A better way with legacy Polymer is that the mixin CSS variables map to actual native CSS variables you can reference.

So, instead of:

```js
css`
paper-card {
  --paper-card-header-text:{
    color: blue;
  }
}`
```

Call the underlying property of the mixin:

```js
css`
paper-card {
  --paper-card-header-text_-_color: blue;
}`
```

However, in the specific case of the header colour `<paper-card>` also a direct variable:

```js
css`
paper-card {
  --paper-card-header-color: blue;
}`
```